# removing query strings from static resources in wordpress site

Tags: wordpress

I have tried with query strings from Autoptimize plugin and used another plugin Remove Query Strings From Static Resources but still their are some strings in my website.Can i know how to remove this.

```
http://stagingserver.com/website/wp-content/plugins/revslider/public/assets/js/extensions/revolution.extension.actions.min.js?version=5.4.7
http://stagingserver.com/website/wp-content/plugins/revslider/public/assets/js/extensions/revolution.extension.layeranimation.min.js?version=5.4.7
 http://stagingserver.com/website/wp-content/plugins/revslider/public/assets/js/extensions/revolution.extension.navigation.min.js?version=5.4.7
 http://stagingserver.com/website/wp-content/plugins/revslider/public/assets/js/extensions/revolution.extension.slideanims.min.js?version=5.4.7
 https://connect.facebook.net/signals/config/324909608302161?v=2.8.33&r=stable
 https://livesupporti.com/Scripts/ClientGUI.js?v=201
 https://livesupporti.com/Scripts/ajaxfileupload.js?v=1
 https://livesupporti.com/Scripts/clientAsync.js?acc=5fadb109-5c10-4017-b656-ced9964ace35&skin=Classic
 https://livesupporti.com/Scripts/clientCrossdomainFunctionsAsync.js?v=25
 https://seal.godaddy.com/getSeal?sealID=lglqBjudZPUepPaFaChH9FWPKUhY63v6YZKzbGixRyu85G1w2JhF80LP0FLF
```

My website is developed on woocomerce.I have found this issues while checking performance speed in GTMatric.

Comment: Why would you want to remove version string from js file though? You will not know what version of the library you are downloading

Comment: @WilliamChong      For checking the performance speed  i haved checked in GTMatric.It shows to fix this to increase performance speed.

Comment: Those version strings are there for a reason though. You don't want to have them unexpectedly change version, it might break your website.